# How to have one or non index in vue when I not using vue file?

Tags: vue.js

I build a vue project using vue/cli.

Now all my typescript and html and scss they placed inside one vue file.

I want to sperate them to septate files (`.ts, .html, .scss`).

What I did is create a folder (card component) inside I have:

```
card.component.ts
card.component.scss
card.component.html
```

and I also have

index.vue

```
<template src="./card.component.html"></template>
<script lang="ts" src="./card.component.ts"></script>
<style lang="scss" scoped src="./card.component.scss"></style>
```

and index.ts

```
export { default } from './index.vue';
```

I import component using:

```
components: { card: import('./card') };
```

Is it possible to not have `index.vue` and `index.ts`? Or just have one index file? (and still have using the vue/cli)

Comment: Wouldn't this be more of a code smell? If the component is so big it needs to be separated like this, it should probably be broken down into smaller child components.

Separate files just adds more complexity with no real gain here and takes away the power of a single file vue component

Comment: I have monorepo and Vetur not play well - when I have more than one projects. but in one typescript file is okay the lint is good